# TCP connection refused with FFMPEG

Tags: tcp, ffmpeg

OFFICIAL EDIT:

I thank you so much for your help but I am still encountering problems.

My ffserver.conf file is like this:

```
# Port on which the server is listening. You must select a different
# port from your standard HTTP web server if it is running on the same
# computer.
HTTPPort 8090

# Address on which the server is bound. Only useful if you have
# several network interfaces.
HTTPBindAddress 0.0.0.0

# Number of simultaneous HTTP connections that can be handled. It has
# to be defined *before* the MaxClients parameter, since it defines the
# MaxClients maximum limit.
MaxHTTPConnections 2000

# Number of simultaneous requests that can be handled. Since FFServer
# is very fast, it is more likely that you will want to leave this high
# and use MaxBandwidth, below.
MaxClients 1000

# This the maximum amount of kbit/sec that you are prepared to
# consume when streaming to clients.
MaxBandwidth 1000

# Access log file (uses standard Apache log file format)
# '-' is the standard output.
CustomLog -

##################################################################
# Definition of the live feeds. Each live feed contains one video
# and/or audio sequence coming from an ffmpeg encoder or another
# ffserver. This sequence may be encoded simultaneously with several
# codecs at several resolutions.

<Feed feed1.ffm>

# You must use 'ffmpeg' to send a live feed to ffserver. In this
# example, you can type:
#
# ffmpeg http://localhost:8090/feed1.ffm

# ffserver can also do time shifting. It means that it can stream any
# previously recorded live stream. The request should contain:
# "http://xxxx?date=[YYYY-MM-DDT][[HH:]MM:]SS[.m...]".You must specify
# a path where the feed is stored on disk. You also specify the
# maximum size of the feed, where zero means unlimited. Default:
# File=/tmp/feed_name.ffm FileMaxSize=5M
File /tmp/feed1.ffm
FileMaxSize 200K

# You could specify
# ReadOnlyFile /saved/specialvideo.ffm
# This marks the file as readonly and it will not be deleted or updated.

# Specify launch in order to start ffmpeg automatically.
# First ffmpeg must be defined with an appropriate path if needed,
# after that options can follow, but avoid adding the http:// field
#Launch ffmpeg

# Only allow connections from localhost to the feed.
#ACL allow 127.0.0.1
#ACL allow 189.34.0.158
</Feed>


##################################################################
# Now you can define each stream which will be generated from the
# original audio and video stream. Each format has a filename (here
# 'test1.mpg'). FFServer will send this stream when answering a
# request containing this filename.

<Stream test1.mpg>

# coming from live feed 'feed1'
Feed feed1.ffm

# Format of the stream : you can choose among:
# mpeg       : MPEG-1 multiplexed video and audio
# mpegvideo  : only MPEG-1 video
# mp2        : MPEG-2 audio (use AudioCodec to select layer 2 and 3 codec)
# ogg        : Ogg format (Vorbis audio codec)
# rm         : RealNetworks-compatible stream. Multiplexed audio and video.
# ra         : RealNetworks-compatible stream. Audio only.
# mpjpeg     : Multipart JPEG (works with Netscape without any plugin)
# jpeg       : Generate a single JPEG image.
# asf        : ASF compatible streaming (Windows Media Player format).
# swf        : Macromedia Flash compatible stream
# avi        : AVI format (MPEG-4 video, MPEG audio sound)
Format mpeg

# Bitrate for the audio stream. Codecs usually support only a few
# different bitrates.
AudioBitRate 32

# Number of audio channels: 1 = mono, 2 = stereo
AudioChannels 1

# Sampling frequency for audio. When using low bitrates, you should
# lower this frequency to 22050 or 11025. The supported frequencies
# depend on the selected audio codec.
AudioSampleRate 44100

# Bitrate for the video stream
VideoBitRate 64

# Ratecontrol buffer size
VideoBufferSize 40

# Number of frames per second
VideoFrameRate 3

# Size of the video frame: WxH (default: 160x128)
# The following abbreviations are defined: sqcif, qcif, cif, 4cif, qqvga,
# qvga, vga, svga, xga, uxga, qxga, sxga, qsxga, hsxga, wvga, wxga, wsxga,
# wuxga, woxga, wqsxga, wquxga, whsxga, whuxga, cga, ega, hd480, hd720,
# hd1080
VideoSize 160x128

# Transmit only intra frames (useful for low bitrates, but kills frame rate).
#VideoIntraOnly

# If non-intra only, an intra frame is transmitted every VideoGopSize
# frames. Video synchronization can only begin at an intra frame.
VideoGopSize 12

# More MPEG-4 parameters
# VideoHighQuality
# Video4MotionVector

# Choose your codecs:
#AudioCodec mp2
#VideoCodec mpeg1video

# Suppress audio
#NoAudio

# Suppress video
#NoVideo

#VideoQMin 3
#VideoQMax 31

# Set this to the number of seconds backwards in time to start. Note that
# most players will buffer 5-10 seconds of video, and also you need to allow
# for a keyframe to appear in the data stream.
#Preroll 15

# ACL:

# You can allow ranges of addresses (or single addresses)
#ACL ALLOW <first address> <last address>

# You can deny ranges of addresses (or single addresses)
#ACL DENY <first address> <last address>

# You can repeat the ACL allow/deny as often as you like. It is on a per
# stream basis. The first match defines the action. If there are no matches,
# then the default is the inverse of the last ACL statement.
#
# Thus 'ACL allow localhost' only allows access from localhost.
# 'ACL deny 1.0.0.0 1.255.255.255' would deny the whole of network 1 and
# allow everybody else.

</Stream>


##################################################################
# Example streams


# Multipart JPEG

#<Stream test.mjpg>
#Feed feed1.ffm
#Format mpjpeg
#VideoFrameRate 2
#VideoIntraOnly
#NoAudio
#Strict -1
#</Stream>


# Single JPEG

#<Stream test.jpg>
#Feed feed1.ffm
#Format jpeg
#VideoFrameRate 2
#VideoIntraOnly
##VideoSize 352x240
#NoAudio
#Strict -1
#</Stream>


# Flash

#<Stream test.swf>
#Feed feed1.ffm
#Format swf
#VideoFrameRate 2
#VideoIntraOnly
#NoAudio
#</Stream>


# ASF compatible

<Stream test.asf>
Feed feed1.ffm
Format asf
VideoFrameRate 15
VideoSize 352x240
VideoBitRate 256
VideoBufferSize 40
VideoGopSize 30
AudioBitRate 64
StartSendOnKey
</Stream>


# MP3 audio

#<Stream test.mp3>
#Feed feed1.ffm
#Format mp2
#AudioCodec mp3
#AudioBitRate 64
#AudioChannels 1
#AudioSampleRate 44100
#NoVideo
#</Stream>


# Ogg Vorbis audio

#<Stream test.ogg>
#Feed feed1.ffm
#Metadata title "Stream title"
#AudioBitRate 64
#AudioChannels 2
#AudioSampleRate 44100
#NoVideo
#</Stream>


# Real with audio only at 32 kbits

#<Stream test.ra>
#Feed feed1.ffm
#Format rm
#AudioBitRate 32
#NoVideo
#NoAudio
#</Stream>


# Real with audio and video at 64 kbits

#<Stream test.rm>
#Feed feed1.ffm
#Format rm
#AudioBitRate 32
#VideoBitRate 128
#VideoFrameRate 25
#VideoGopSize 25
#NoAudio
#</Stream>


##################################################################
# A stream coming from a file: you only need to set the input
# filename and optionally a new format. Supported conversions:
#    AVI -> ASF

#<Stream file.rm>
#File "/usr/local/httpd/htdocs/tlive.rm"
#NoAudio
#</Stream>

#<Stream file.asf>
#File "/usr/local/httpd/htdocs/test.asf"
#NoAudio
#Metadata author "Me"
#Metadata copyright "Super MegaCorp"
#Metadata title "Test stream from disk"
#Metadata comment "Test comment"
#</Stream>


##################################################################
# RTSP examples
#
# You can access this stream with the RTSP URL:
#   rtsp://localhost:5454/test1-rtsp.mpg
#
# A non-standard RTSP redirector is also created. Its URL is:
#   http://localhost:8090/test1-rtsp.rtsp

#<Stream test1-rtsp.mpg>
#Format rtp
#File "/usr/local/httpd/htdocs/test1.mpg"
#</Stream>


# Transcode an incoming live feed to another live feed,
# using libx264 and video presets

#<Stream live.h264>
#Format rtp
#Feed feed1.ffm
#VideoCodec libx264
#VideoFrameRate 24
#VideoBitRate 100
#VideoSize 480x272
#AVPresetVideo default
#AVPresetVideo baseline
#AVOptionVideo flags +global_header
#
#AudioCodec libfaac
#AudioBitRate 32
#AudioChannels 2
#AudioSampleRate 22050
#AVOptionAudio flags +global_header
#</Stream>

##################################################################
# SDP/multicast examples
#
# If you want to send your stream in multicast, you must set the
# multicast address with MulticastAddress. The port and the TTL can
# also be set.
#
# An SDP file is automatically generated by ffserver by adding the
# 'sdp' extension to the stream name (here
# http://localhost:8090/test1-sdp.sdp). You should usually give this
# file to your player to play the stream.
#
# The 'NoLoop' option can be used to avoid looping when the stream is
# terminated.

#<Stream test1-sdp.mpg>
#Format rtp
#File "/usr/local/httpd/htdocs/test1.mpg"
#MulticastAddress 224.124.0.1
#MulticastPort 5000
#MulticastTTL 16
#NoLoop
#</Stream>


##################################################################
# Special streams

# Server status

<Stream stat.html>
Format status

# Only allow local people to get the status
ACL allow localhost
ACL allow 192.168.0.0 192.168.255.255

#FaviconURL http://pond1.gladstonefamily.net:8080/favicon.ico
</Stream>


# Redirect index.html to the appropriate site

<Redirect index.html>
URL http://www.ffmpeg.org/
</Redirect>
```

I started my server and executed:

```
ffserver -d -f /usr/share/doc/ffmpeg-2.6.8/ffserver.conf
```

No error message and everything looks fine.

After that I execute this (in your answer, I think you forgot the port number):

```
ffmpeg -i "rtsp://200.180.90.95:554/onvif1" -r 25 -s 640x480 -c:v libx264 -flags +global_header -f flv "http://45.79.207.38:8090/feed1.ffm"
```

Then I get this log:

```
  libavutil      54. 20.100 / 54. 20.100
  libavcodec     56. 26.100 / 56. 26.100
  libavformat    56. 25.101 / 56. 25.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 11.102 /  5. 11.102
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
[h264 @ 0x1a23580] RTP: missed 1 packets
[pcm_alaw @ 0x1a24360] RTP: missed 2 packets
[h264 @ 0x1a23580] RTP: missed 1 packets
Invalid UE golomb code
[h264 @ 0x1a23580] cbp too large (3199971767) at 76 33
[h264 @ 0x1a23580] error while decoding MB 76 33
[h264 @ 0x1a23580] Cannot use next picture in error concealment
[h264 @ 0x1a23580] concealing 933 DC, 933 AC, 933 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0x1a23580] RTP: missed 1 packets
[h264 @ 0x1a23580] cbp too large (62) at 50 24
[h264 @ 0x1a23580] error while decoding MB 50 24
[h264 @ 0x1a23580] Cannot use next picture in error concealment
[h264 @ 0x1a23580] concealing 1679 DC, 1679 AC, 1679 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0x1a23580] RTP: missed 2 packets
[h264 @ 0x1a23580] Cannot use next picture in error concealment
[h264 @ 0x1a23580] concealing 1965 DC, 1965 AC, 1965 MV errors in P frame
[pcm_alaw @ 0x1a24360] RTP: missed 1 packets
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x1a23580] RTP: missed 3 packets
[h264 @ 0x1a23580] mb_type 49 in P slice too large at 74 25
[h264 @ 0x1a23580] error while decoding MB 74 25
[h264 @ 0x1a23580] Cannot use next picture in error concealment
[h264 @ 0x1a23580] concealing 1575 DC, 1575 AC, 1575 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0x1a23580] RTP: missed 2 packets
[h264 @ 0x1a23580] P sub_mb_type 29 out of range at 30 26
[h264 @ 0x1a23580] error while decoding MB 30 26
[h264 @ 0x1a23580] Cannot use next picture in error concealment
[h264 @ 0x1a23580] concealing 1539 DC, 1539 AC, 1539 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0x1a23580] RTP: missed 1 packets
[h264 @ 0x1a23580] out of range intra chroma pred mode at 72 29
[h264 @ 0x1a23580] error while decoding MB 72 29
[h264 @ 0x1a23580] Cannot use next picture in error concealment
[h264 @ 0x1a23580] concealing 1257 DC, 1257 AC, 1257 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0x1a23580] RTP: missed 3 packets
[h264 @ 0x1a23580] negative number of zero coeffs at 48 5
[h264 @ 0x1a23580] error while decoding MB 48 5
[h264 @ 0x1a23580] Cannot use next picture in error concealment
[h264 @ 0x1a23580] concealing 3201 DC, 3201 AC, 3201 MV errors in P frame
[pcm_alaw @ 0x1a24360] RTP: missed 1 packets
[rtsp @ 0x1a20ee0] decoding for stream 0 failed
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.1 : mono
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://200.180.90.95:554/onvif1':
  Metadata:
    title           : H.264 Video, RtspServer_0.0.0.2
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Baseline), yuv420p, 1280x720, 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_alaw, 8000 Hz, 1 channels, s16, 64 kb/s
[libx264 @ 0x1b728a0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA3 LZCNT BMI2
[libx264 @ 0x1b728a0] profile High, level 3.0
[libx264 @ 0x1b728a0] 264 - core 142 r2495 6a301b6 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2014 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=1 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
[flv @ 0x1a66300] FLV does not support sample rate 8000, choose from (44100, 22050, 11025)
[flv @ 0x1a66300] Audio codec mp3 not compatible with flv
Output #0, flv, to 'http://45.79.207.38:8090/feed1.ffm':
  Metadata:
    title           : H.264 Video, RtspServer_0.0.0.2
    encoder         : Lavf56.25.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([7][0][0][0] / 0x0007), yuv420p, 640x480, q=-1--1, 25 fps, 1k tbn, 25 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.26.100 libx264
    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3 (libmp3lame) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), 8000 Hz, mono, s16p
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.26.100 libmp3lame
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (pcm_alaw (native) -> mp3 (libmp3lame))
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Function not implemented
```

I am doing this in a clean install of CENTOS, no customization. Could you please helpe me?

Comment: `ffmpeg -i "rtsp://ip_of_my_cam:554/onvif1" -r 25 -s 640x480 -c:v libx264 -flags +global_header -f flv "rtmp://:1010/live/livestream1"`its missing domain name. rtmp://<domain-name>:1010/live/livestream1. Test this stream using VLC Media player and make sure that stream is live

Comment: @Mohd Asim Suhail what domain name should I use? The IP of my server? localhost? 127.0.0.1?

Comment: the rtmp URL should be complete, if you want to host locally then use localhost, otherwise your public IP.

Comment: I just did that, I replace in the comand "rtmp://:1010/live/livestream1" FOR "rtmp://IP_OF_MY_SERVER:1010/live/livestream1" but FFMPEG still returns error "Connection refused". I cannot even try to use it in VLC cause FFMPEG is not even allowing the connection to begin

Comment: is VLC able to play rtsp://ip_of_my_cam:554/onvif1 ?

Comment: Just to make clear, I didt this -->> ffmpeg -i "rtsp://IP_OF_MY_CAM:554/onvif1" -r 25 -s 640x480 -c:v libx264 -flags +global_header -f flv "rtmp://IP_OF_MY_SERVER:1010/live/livestream1" <<-- but I still get connection refused

Comment: @Mohd Asim Suhail yes, using RTSP VLC works fine

Comment: do I need to enable this port 1010 somewhere in FFMPEG? Cause I just installed FFMPEG, I didnt do any change to its configuration files.

Comment: No you don't have to enable, once try to change output port number maybe some service is running on 1010 ( on linux you can check ports used by netstat -tunlp ).

Comment: I used the port 8090 which was on top of my file ffserver.conf and now it looks like I get another error. BROKEN PIPE. Any idea?

Comment: i am trying to replicate same scenario on my system , will update when i am done, must be some small mistake only. :P

Comment: thank you so much! I will allow you my cam ok? I will provide you the IP of my cam so you can try. I edited the question with the new line, please try it

Comment: I got the problem, first we have to run rtmp server, then we have to run ffmpeg command and point the output to the RTMP server port. that is why it shows connection refused. https://github.com/LiminWang/simple-rtmp-server or nginx also offers rtmp support, first run RTMP server and then FFMPEG command with port Number configured in RTMP server

Comment: @Mohd Asim Suhail thnk you!! I am not an expert with ffmpeg nor RTMP I am just trying to export RTMP to RSTP so my grandpa surveilance cam work. Would you mind post a reply so I can accept with the command in linux to start rtmp? So far I just execute "ffserver -d -f /usr/share/doc/ffmpeg-2.6.8/ffserver.conf" and afer that I try to execute the line ffmpeg -i "rtsp://200.180.90.95:554/onvif1" -r 25 -s 640x480 -c:v libx264 -flags +global_header -f flv "rtmp://45.79.207.38:8090/live/livestream1"

Comment: I took a read at https://github.com/LiminWang/simple-rtmp-server and it looks very overcomplicated! I saw other tutorials online how to convert rtsp to rtmp and it was always simple and didnt need that...

Comment: do you know how can I convert rtsp to an html page if it's easier? I dont really need rtmp, if ffmpeg can export to html to me it would be fine

Comment: Cool give me some time, I will post the tutorial. Are you aware of nginx ??

Comment: no, sorry, no nginx. I found this otther command online maybe its easir? -->>  ffmpeg -i "rtsp://200.180.90.95:554/onvif1" -r 25 -s 640x480 -c:v libx264 -flags +global_header -f flv "http://45.79.207.38:8090/feed1.ffm"

Comment: Would you mind seeing my EDIT 2? Maybe using http instead of RTMP could be easier?

Comment: @Samul have you managed to get the output yet? if yes pleas let me know i am trying to figure out the same scenario for days and i still get the broken pipe error.

Answer (score 1):

When you installed ffmpeg (`yum install ffmpeg`), along with ffmpeg,ffserver is also installed.

Step 1: Configure ffserver (config file located in /etc/ffserver.conf), configure `HTTPPort` to any available port. `<Feed feed1.ffm> .... </Feed>` this  block describes the input point for server feed. and `<Stream test1.mpg> .. </Stream>` block in output. Final output stream is decided by this block.

Step 2: Start ffserver by typing `ffserver` in command line (if you want to run it in background then 'nohup ffserver &')

Step 3: ffmpeg -i "rtsp://200.180.90.95:554/onvif1" -r 25 -s 640x480 -c:v libx264 -flags +global_header -f flv "http://45.79.207.38:/feed1.ffm"

NOTE: Streaming video requires higher internet bandwidth.

Comment: My friend, I read everything you said, then I tested it and detailed it in the question (EDITED) but I still get error. Could you please take a look at that? I am not doing anything abnormal, I am just using default configurations of ffmpeg and nothing more.